# Back button behavior differs depending on whether I entered activity from the nav drawer or from a UI element

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-button, navigation-drawer, pull-to-refresh

I created a `NavigationDrawerFragment`, which is actually just a slightly modified version of the code Android Studio generates.

I have a `Dashboard` activity that contains `NavigationDrawerFragment` and that can launch several other activities, each of which also contain the `NavigationDrawerFragment`.  Let's call one of these activities `Foo`.

If I enter `Foo` from the `Dashboard` using the Dashboard's nav drawer, then open Foo's nav drawer, the `back button` will correctly close the nav drawer.  **HOWEVER**, if I entered `Foo` using a `UI element` (that was in place before I implemented a nav drawer), then open Foo's nav drawer, the `back button` returns to the Dashboard activity rather than closing the nav drawer.

I can't figure out why this is occuring.  For the `NavigationDrawerFragment` I have an `ItemClickListener` and for the `UI element` I have a `ClickListener`, but in both situations I am launching a new `Foo` activity using an `intent`.

I am wondering if there is something being set that I just don't realize, and if I have control over that something.

I know that I could override `onBackPressed` to check for the drawer being open (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22183764/1747491)), but that feels hacky as there is obviously some behavior happening here that I am not aware of.

**Edit:** <strike>This has something to do with [ActionBar-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh).  I removed it from `Foo` and the nav drawer works correctly.</strike>

**Edit 2:** I was wrong about pull-to-refresh, as @adneal pointed out. There must have been a coincidence that made me think that.  I ended up overriding `onBackPressed` and conditionally checking if the drawer is open or not.  Also as @adneal pointed out, the problem has to do with focus.  I am still so very curious as to how the focus could be different when launching the activities the same way, but from different places.

Comment: So, when you press the "back" button after starting `Foo` from a `View.OnClickListener`, the `DrawerLayout` in `Foo` doesn't close and instead you go back to your previous `Activity`. Is that right?

Comment: @adneal That is exactly right.

Comment: Sorry, but I want to be even more clear. Your `DrawerLayout` in `Foo`, being fully visible after you drag it out, does not respond to the "back" button being pressed when you launch `Foo` from a `View.OnClickListener`, but does respond when you launch it in the same manner from an `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`? Also, how are you implementing your `NavigationDrawerFragment`? Is it embedded the in layout of your `Activity` or do your use a `FragmentTransaction`?

Comment: @adneal What you described is exactly right, and it is embedded in the Activity's `layout`.  I just discovered an important clue, the error doesn't occur if I remove Chris Bane's `PullToRefresh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm fairly certain I understand what's going on, but I'm still unsure about why it only seem to happen when you use a `View.OnClicklistener`. Maybe there's a little more to your code that I don't know about or maybe I overlooked something in those regards.

But the reason you're having this problem is due to how Android handles the `View.onKey...` event. `DrawerLayout` overrides `View.onKeyDown` and `View.onKeyUp`, checking each time if you're pressing the "back" button so it can determine whether or not to close the drawer. But this event isn't taking place, in your case, because the `AdapterView` you have set will take the focus away from the `DrawerLayout` after you call `AdapterView.setAdpater`.

**How to fix it**

Short of copying over the `DrawerLayout` source and modifying it, which you could definitely do; it's only one class, I would recommend converting each `Foo` `Activity` into a `Fragment`, then use the `FrameLayout` you typically place when creating a `DrawerLayout` to display them. You should create a `NavigationDrawerActivity` instead of a `Fragment` to host everything.

This has to do with the way `DrawerLayout` is laid out, in that it has to use `MeasureSpec.EXACTLY`. In other words, when you place your `NavigationDrawerFragment` ontop of your `Foo` layout, it takes up the entire space. If you called `View.setFocusableInTouchMode` after you set your `ListAdapter` in `Foo`, the `DrawerLayout` would work like it should, but the `AdapterView` wouldn't scroll anymore. And you can't toggle that focus based on the open or closed position of the `DrawerLayout`, because either way it takes up the entire space and always return `true` in `View.onTouchEvent`.

Or just override `Activity.onBackPressed`, which really isn't as "hacky" as you may think, but I understand what you mean.

At any rate, I hope this is clear and/or helpful at the very least. Took me a little bit to reproduce your problem, but after I did it didn't take long to rule out the pull-to-refresh library. In short, I think it's a focus issue. Prove me wrong.

**Source**

[You can view the source for the `DrawerLayout` here to look over how it handles the "back" event](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.java#L1221)

[You can see here how `AdapterView.checkFocus` works](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/AdapterView.java#L711)

[You can see here in `ListView` (`GridView` is the same), when `AdapterView.checkFocus` is called](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java#L481)

Comment: You are absolutely correct about `pull-to-refresh` not being involved.  Some coincidence must have made me think that.  You are also correct that it is a focus issue.  I have an `EditText` above the `ListView` in `Foo`, and if I put focus on it, then close the keyboard, the `back button` will always go back an `activity` instead of closing the drawer. Maybe overriding `onBackPressed` is the proper way to do this?

Comment: I am still so very curious what is causing the difference when I launch `Foo` from Dashboard's nav drawer, or launch `Foo` using the UI element.  Is Android doing something under the hood to make the `Drawer` have focus when I go to `Foo` from a Drawer?

Comment: Regarding your recommendation to move to a one activity approach, I want to do that but I didn't have time to engage in that large of a refactor (this is a project I am on at work).  Instead I decided to at least put all of my old activities into fragments for now, and maybe go with a one activity approach in the future.  So essentially, every activity has one main fragment at the moment.

Comment: No, it is not. I'll probably dig into this some more later, I'm curious too. But that would certainly be the simplest solution. On a completely unrelated note, I grew up in Clinton about two hours from Starkville. Eh, thought it was kinda interesting.