# Android, handle onBackPressed while drawer is showing

Tags: android, drawer

In default, when the drawer is showing and you press the `BackButton` it automatically close.
but I want when it's showing and user clicks on `BackButton`, close the app.
I tried these solution but didn't work :

[Navigation drawer, handling the back button to go to previous fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093287/navigation-drawer-handling-the-back-button-to-go-to-previous-fragments)

[Backbutton press from android navigation drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22183466/backbutton-press-from-android-navigation-drawer)

Comment: have a boolean to check if navigation drawer is open in _onBackPressed()_

Comment: I did it but it doesn't check if clause when the drawer is open.

Answer (score 0):

First override back pressed of your activity and then can check if drawer is open

```
mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START);
```

If this return true simply close your app.

**Important** : Check your drawer gravity.

Try registering you fragment to back pressed like this:

```
public void registerBackButton()
{
    if (getView() != null)
    {
        getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        getView().requestFocus();
        final BaseFragment frag = this;
        getView().setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
                if (event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
                    {
                        if (isVisible())
                        {
                            return frag.onFragmentBackPressed();
                        }
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now in onFragmentBackPressed check if drawer is opened or not as mentioned above.

Comment: it doesn't check if clause when the drawer is open.

Comment: you meant to say that onBackPressed is not called??

Comment: Yes !
check buy yourself

Answer (score 0):

`onBackPressed` will not be called on drawer open or lets say if your keyboard is open then also your back key changes to down arrow. So when you press that down key your keyboard hides and your `onBackPressed` will not be called still.

Your app will be closed when you press the back button again. Same is the case with keyboard.

So first close the drawer, then press back button again, and then your app will finish